# Prevent Jenkins node from running out of disk space

Tags: jenkins, devops, disk, cicd

I have four separate pipelines that all run on the same node. Recently, I've been getting errors that look like this:

```
Disk space is too low. Only 0.315GB left on /var/jenkins.
```

I've already reconfigured the pipelines to get rid of old logs and builds after 7 days. Aside from this, are there any plugins or shell commands I can run post-build to keep my disk space free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those problems that can be fixed/monitoried in multiple ways.

If you're willing to you can set up something like [datadog](http://datadoghq.com) or [nagios](https://nagios.org) to monitor your system and alert you when something is starting to fill up your `/var/jenkins`.

You can also set up a cron that checks and emails you when something is starting to fill up.

But if you'd like to figure **why** it's filling up, it's possible that your `/var` partition is too small, but without seeing your disk partition layout it's hard to give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I Have faced same issue with the one of the jenkins node

solution: Ssh to your slave and do this df -h, it will show disk info, and available space in /tmp and increase tmp size by

## sudo mount -o remount /tmp